# Wrapping lambda as std::function produces wrong results (was The dangers of template argument deduction)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Returning a certain lambda wrapped as an `std::function` produces wrong results:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
std::function<const T&()> constant(const T& c) {
  return [c]() noexcept -> const T&{ return c; };
}

template <typename T>
std::function<std::tuple<T>()> zip(const std::function<T()>& f) {
  return [f]() { return std::tuple{f()}; };
}

int main() {
    const auto good = [f = constant(1.0)]() { return std::tuple{f()}; };
    const auto bad = zip(constant(1.0));
    std::cout << "good: " << std::get<0>(good()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bad:  " << std::get<0>(bad()) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
good: 1
bad:  6.95282e-310
```

It looks like undefined behaviour. What is going on?

Comment: The capture by value of the lambda will not capture a reference! It will actually store the value of c in a const int inside the lambda!

Comment: Your complaint basically boils down to "`std::tuple{/* const ref expression*/}` deduces to `std::tuple<value>` and `std::tuple<value>` implicitly converts to `std::tuple<const value &>`"? Both of those things are desirable behaviour.

Comment: @PepijnKramer You are correct, but that was the intended behaviour! I want the lambda returned by constant() to be the only owner of the object.

Comment: @Caleth I agree with you, I was not complaining :-) The price to pay for having those desirable things are some potential headaches, though, but this is nothing unusual in C++ :-D

Comment: Maybe you could/should formulate the problem part as  a question, and move the solution part to a self-answer, seeing as how SO is a QA site. Also, this is not a forum, so direct "comments and discussion" doesn't quite work here.

Comment: Fair point! I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the following: the tuple created inside zip is automatically deduced to be a `std::tuple<double>`, but zip returns a `std::function<std::tuple<const double&>()>`. The returned tuple contains a reference to a temporary, which is undefined behaviour.

The fix is simply explicitly adding the type of the tuple element:

```
template <typename T>
std::function<std::tuple<T>()> zip(const std::function<T()>& f) {
      return [f]() { return std::tuple<T>{f()}; };
//was return [f]() { return std::tuple{f()}; };
}
```

#### Rant...

Boiling down the issue in my source code to this was very nasty. For one, debugging these lambdas packed into `std::function`s is not fun. I tried g++'s `-fsanitize=undefined`, but this was not caught, although it catches the missing return type in this function:

```
template <typename T>
std::function<const T&()> constant_bad(const T& c) {
  return [c]() noexcept { return c; };
}
```

I filed a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102095) in GCC.

I would appreciate other comments and discussion about this issue! For example, would it be good, if possible, that compilers warn about this type of implicit conversion? Eg when implicitly converting a lambda returning `T` into a `std::function<const T&()>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::function<const T& ()> constant(const T& c)
{
    return [c]() noexcept -> const T& 
    { 
        // the captured variable is no longer a reference type!
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(c), std::remove_reference_t<const T&>>);
        return c; 
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto fn = constant(42);
    auto answer = fn();
}
```